# Bulk adding plots to Bokeh

Tags: python, python-2.7, bokeh

I would like to add 10,000 lines to a `bokeh` plot based on two points for each line. Adding them 1 by 1 is incredibly slow and can take up to an hour. Is there any way to speed this up?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
output_file('temp.html')

p = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=400)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10000, 4)), columns=['x1', 'x2', 'y1', 'y2'])
print df
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    p.line([row['x1'], row['x2']], [row['y1'], row['y2']], line_width=2)

show(p)
```

EDIT:

with Multiline

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models.glyphs import MultiLine
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

output_file('temp.html')

p = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=400,
           )
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10000, 4)), columns=['x1', 'x2', 'y1', 'y2'])
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    xs=df[['x1', 'x2']].as_matrix(),
    ys=df[['y1', 'y2']].as_matrix(),
)
)

glyph = MultiLine(xs="xs", ys="ys", line_color="#8073ac", line_width=2)
p.add_glyph(source, glyph)
show(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: for this specific application with single segment lines, the best solution is to use the vectorized `segment` glyph method.

Bokeh is not the right tool, at least not by itself, for this kind of usage. In order to support all sorts of interactive features, Bokeh is explicitly optimized for fewer glyphs, with more data per glyph. Every new glyph incurs fixed overhead, and 10000 glyphs will never be reasonable with Bokeh by itself. One option might be to make a single call to `multi_line` with all the data for all the lines, instead of many thousands of distinct calls to `line`. However, you might also want to look at [Datashader](http://datashader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is useful for visualizing larger data sets (up to billions of points) and which integrates seamlessly with Bokeh to provide interactivity over such data sets.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into Datashader, but for now want to try `Multiline`.  Using this documentation https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/multi_line.html. I edited the original question with the updated code, but now just get a blank chart

Comment: Actually, is your data really always single segment lines with only start/end and no other points? if so you should be using `segment`, which exists to vectorize that kind of visual and will be easier to prepare data for than `multi_line` https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.segment

Comment: yes, each row in my dataframe represents x0, x1, y0, y1. I took a quick look at the documentation and that looks like the right application.

Comment: just did a test, from multiple hours to about 4 seconds!